# How often are deferred emails retried? Is it possible to get a heads up on emails that are deferred/delayed?

Tags: email

What exactly are the delivery status notification policies for SalesForce? I'm experiencing an issue where I only find out about deferred/delayed emails after SalesForce has completely given up a day later.

I'd like to know if there are any delay issues ASAP so I can be reasonably certain if emails are queuing up on the SalesForce side.

For example, for non-salesforce going through my mail server, I'll receive a courtesy notification after an outbound email has been delayed/deferred on my end for 4 hours.  Is something like that available with SalesForce?  Or should I expect the only notification for deferred emails to be the final "I've given up complete" email at the very end of the queue lifetime?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this information is not available to us.  Most likely this information isn't stored in Salesforce, it's completely deferred to the email server.  Assuming the email is accepted by the email server (example case where it's not: malformed to address), it's fire-and-forget, with errors handled by the email server.

The messages you receive are all standard email server messages.